# Flutter ScrollController finout max offset

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to make some kind of custom scroll progress indicator for CustomScrollView.

```
_scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_scroll);

void _scroll() {
    print('scrolled ${_scrollController.offset} from {??}');
}
```

Is there way to findout _scrollController max offset?

Or could I get some value form Scrollbar widget?

Comment: What about `scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent`?

Comment: @Volleyball well this is exactly what im looking for. If you will add it as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So all you need is

```
scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent
```

This gives you the max scroll extent for the `ListView`